# Integrating Chromecast into application supporting ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, google-cast, chromecast

I'm integrating chromecast into my existing application supporting ActionBarSherlock.
I followed this link http://www.droidorbit.com/2013/10/mediarouter-and-actionbarsherlock.html.
But I got the error in compile time:

```
MediaRouterJellybean cannot be resolved to a type.  
MediaRouterJellybeanMr1 cannot be resolved to a type  
MediaRouterJellybeanMr2 cannot be resolved to a type  in SystemMediaRouteProvider.java file.  
R.attr.isLightTheme cannot be resolved or is not a field in MediaRouterThemeHelper.java file.
```

I currently comments these code for error free, then integrate with the Cast sample project. In the project I display cast icon in the ActionBar with `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider` instead of using `MediaRouteButton`. But I got the error in run time in `onCreateOptionMenu()`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider cannot be cast to com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider
```

I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.
P/S: Could anyone give instructions modifying MediaRouter lib using Eclipse.

Comment: You may want to post to the same blog that you followed

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.

Just comment the code in `isLightTheme()` function and return false.
Copy 3 files `MediaRouterJellybean.java, MediaRouterJellybeanMr1.java, MediaRouterJellybeanMr2.java` into packet `android.support.v7.media`.
At that time, you still get the error

```
MediaRouterJellybeanMr2 cannot be resolved to a type  in SystemMediaRouteProvider.
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set target version = 18, right-click project, select `Android Tool -> Clear Lint Marker`.
P/S: I'm using **Eclipse**, not Android studio.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, you should post it to the blog too, I was going to email you to know if you had fixed it :)

Comment: I already fixed it. If you need, I'll send you my modified support-v7-mediarouter lib. But now I use support-v7-appcombat, and I prefer you use this. :)

Comment: I am converting my project to appcombat. Did you find any solution to replace SherlockPreferenceActivity?

Comment: I didn’t need to create a Preference section yet so I haven’t tried, but I think you can use this library, and use a fragment instead of activity:
https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment